# Python check for redirect after Login on a php page

Tags: python, python-requests

I created a small python script to log into a php page.
The page itselfs redirects me to another page, if I log in (from Login.php to Userpanel.php).

Now I want to check if I get redirected after the Post Request - so if the Login was successfull.
I expected a statuscode of 3**, but it seems that I'm not getting redirected - even if the login was successfull.

```
r = requests.post(url, allow_redirects = True, data={
            'username': name,
            'password': password
        })
        print(r.status_code)
        print(r.url)
        print(r.history)
```

I want to check, if I get redirected, so I know that the Login was successfull.
Expected a 3** status code, but got a 200.

```
Output:
200 
http://localhost/test/login.php 
[]
```

I first tested the script on my register page and the accounts got inserted into the database, so I know the script itselfs works.

PHP Code:

Disclaimer: This file is just a testfile, so no security checks etc.

```
<?php
            session_start();
            if(isset($_SESSION['name']))
            {
                header("Location: userpanel.php");
            }
        ?>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form method='POST' action=''>
            <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username'/><br/>
            <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'/><br/>
            <input class="btn" type='submit' name='Login'/>  
        </div>
        <?php  
$connection= mysqli_connect("---", "---", "---");
            
            if(!$connection)
                die("---");
            
            if(!mysqli_select_db($connection, "---"))        
            die("---");
            
            if(isset($_POST['Login']))
            {
                $user =  $_POST['username'];
                $pass =  $_POST['password'];

                $result = mysqli_query($verbindung, "SELECT * FROM --- WHERE name='$user' and password='$pass'");

                if($result)
                {
                    if(mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['name']=$user;
                        header("url=userpanel.php");
                    } 
                }                
                mysqli_close($connection);
            }
```

Comment: did you write the php part yourself? can you access and change it?

Comment: @Alimo added the php code

Comment: you keep changing and editing the initial question, while you should add [new edit] after the original question!

Answer (score 0):

```
r = requests.post(url, allow_redirects = True, data={
            'username': name,
            'password': password
        })
print(r.status_code)
print(r.url)
```

you don't have o check the history. url always returns the final url. Nothing is wrong with your python code. can you submit the php code?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check, if I get redirected, so I know that the Login was successfull. Expected a 3** status code, but got a 200.

`requests` will follow redirects by default.

In fact, that's exactly what the ill-named `allow_redirects` tells it to do -- it would be better named `follow_redirects` but alas -- so setting it to `True` is not useful: that's the default and probably what you *don't* want here.

Your options are:

- don't do anything and check the final URL, it's what you're redirecting to, if you've reached the proper final state it should mean your redirection worked
- set `allow_redirects=False`, that way requests will not follow redirects and will just return the first response it gets from the server, even if it's a 3xy
- the response object has [a `history` attribute](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response.history), which contains the "intermediate" responses (every 3xy traversed to reach the final response), so once you get your 200 you can check for the content of this attribute, and maybe the specifics of each response

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed allow_redirects to false, but it's still the same. 
I want to print the history and also the url, but I'm just getting the /Login.php url and the History is empty: []

Comment: That means Requests behaves normally and the problem's elsewhere. Reading the code in more details, instead of checking for the HTTP method used to submit the form you're checking if `isset($_POST['Login'])`, so the PHP code expects a `Login` entry to be set. But in the Python code you're only setting `username` and `password. Note that you could have debugged that rather easily by just adding a bit of tracing (e.g. prints) in the PHP code and followed along with your conditions.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply check the returned HTTP status code, with a redirect it will be 301 or 302. You can use a simple if block to check your r.status_code val.

If the successful login redirection is in the php code, this solution works fine, but if it's a javascript redirection on the login page, you will get a 200 code in the response. If this is the case, you have to search through the returned content. For that, you can use regular expression to check the body of the response for that block of js redirection.

Comment: Their entire issue is that they're not getting a 300 response code. Which happens to be normal, because requests *follows redirects by default*.